# What is the difference between minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex and minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

So in the doc, it says:

`minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex`: For a horizontally scrolling grid, this value represents the minimum spacing between items in the *same column*.

`minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex`: For a horizontally scrolling grid, this value represents the minimum spacing between *successive columns*.

What I guess is if the section count is 1, I should use `minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex`; when section count > 1, I should use `minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex`.

However, I have a horizontal scrolling collection view, the section count is 1, and item count is 2.

When I set `minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex` return 10, it seems nothing happens. When I use `minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex` return 10, the left cell and right cell has 10 space margin, seems working.

So I am confused what does `same column` and `successive columns` meaning here. Could someone explain?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
- collectionView:layout:minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:
```

> Asks the delegate for the spacing between successive rows or columns of a section.
>
> **Discussion**
>   If you do not implement this method, the flow layout uses the value in its minimumLineSpacing property to set the space between lines instead. Your implementation of this method can return a fixed value or return different spacing values for each section.

```
- collectionView:layout:minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:
```

> Asks the delegate for the spacing between successive **items** in the rows or columns of a section.
>
> **Discussion** 
>   If you do not implement this method, the flow layout uses the value in its minimumInteritemSpacing property to set the space between items instead. Your implementation of this method can return a fixed value or return different spacing values for each section.

I believe this is well documented and discussed under [UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout/collectionView:layout:minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:)

**same row.**(for inter item) represents the minimum spacing between items this will determine how many items will be at a single line.

> This is for vertical grid:

```
ex: 
[1]     (interItemSpacing)     [2]     (interItemSpacing)     [3]

[4]     (interItemSpacing)     [5]     (interItemSpacing)     [6]
```

> This is for horizal grid:

```
ex: 
       [1]               [3]                 [5]
(interItemSpacing) (interItemSpacing) (interItemSpacing)
       [2]               [4]                 [6]
```

**successive row.**(for line spacing) represents the minimum spacing between successive rows

> This is for vertical grid:

```
ex: 
    [1]            [2]          [3]

(lineSpacing) (lineSpacing) (lineSpacing)

    [4]            [5]          [6]
```

> This is for horizal grid:

```
ex: 
    [1]     (lineSpacing)       [3]     (lineSpacing)     [5]

    [2]     (lineSpacing)       [4]     (lineSpacing)     [6]
```

Comment: the doc said there is difference for vertical and horizontal; so what I want to know is the horizontal example. Could you update horizontal case?

Comment: you mean the vertical and horizontal grid?

Comment: @Wingzero, there, i edited my answer... is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Wingzero, another thing, don't forget that we are setting the `minimum` so that spacing varies from both `interItemSpacing` and `lineSpacing`.. cheers! :)

Comment: I know, it's just minimum, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex => line with items
minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex => allow line without items